# Redshift join with metadata table and select columns

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, amazon-redshift

I have created a subset of the pg_table_def table with table_name,col_name and data_type. I have also added a column active with 'Y' as value for some of the rows. Let us call this table as config.Table config looks like below:

> ```
> table_name             column_name
> interaction_summary    name_id
> tag_transaction        name_id
> interaction_summary    direct_preference
> bulk_sent              email_image_click
> crm_dm                 web_le_click
> ```

Now I want to be able to map the table names from this table to the actual table and fetch values for the corresponding column. name_id will be the key here which will be available in all tables. My output should look like below:

```
name_id     direct_preference  email_image_click        web_le_click
1            Y                 1                         2
2            N                 1                         2
```

The solution needs to be dynamic so that even if the table list extends tomorrow, the new table should be able to accommodate. Since I am new to Redshift, any help is appreciated. I am also considering to do the same via R using the dplyr package.

Comment: Redshift SQL doesn't support variables or dynamic SQL so this can't be achieved purely in Redshift, you'll need some external process to query the metadata and generate the appropriate select statements. It would also help if you could elaborate on any options you've considered and discarded, or the limitations of your environment e.g. available tools. As it stands this question is too open ended to answer in any detail. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you Nathan. I would be more careful in posting questions going forward. My plan was to run regression analysis on few database table columns using dynamic query. I was able to almost crack it using R. Have answered my question below.!

Answer (score 0):

I understood that dynamic queries don't work with Redshift.
My objective was to pull any new table that comes in and use their columns for regression analysis in R.
I made this working by using listagg feature and concat operation. And then wrote the output to a dataframe in R. This dataframe would have 'n' number of select queries as different rows.
Below is the format:

```
df <- as.data.frame(tbl(conn,sql("select 'select ' || col_names|| ' from ' || table_name as q1 from ( select distinct table_name, listagg(col_name,',') within group (order by col_name)
                                 over (partition by table_name) as col_names
                                 from attribute_config
                                 where active = 'Y'
                                 order by table_name )
                                 group by 1")))
```

Once done, I assigned every row of this dataframe to a new dataframe and fetched the output using below:

> df1 <- tbl(conn,sql(df[1,]))

I know this is a round about solution. But it works !! Fetches about 17M records under 1 second.